# Derivative of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)≠(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition

I'm working on this calculus problem but I'm really stuck, any help would be appreciated

> Let the function $f:ℝ^2 →ℝ$ be defined as:
>
> $f(x,y)=\dfrac{(x^2y)}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)≠(0,0)$
>
> $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$

(a)  Use the definition of partial derivatives to find $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$

I have solved this using limits and arrived at the answer that both partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are zero.

(b)Let $a∈ℝ$ be  a  non-zero  constant  and  let $r(t)=(t,at)$. Show  that $f◦r$
is differentiable and compute $D(f◦r)$

Here I really don't know how to start, I don't how to compute $f◦r$

I think once I the proper function and a general idea of how to approach this problem I'll be able to solve it myself

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$f\circ r$  is just the map $f$ with $t$ instead of $x$'s and $at$ instead of $y$'s. I.e.
$$(f\circ r)(t)=\frac{t^2(at)}{t^2+(at)^2} = \frac{at}{1+a^2}$$
Notice that this is just a scalar function so the derivative is the regular Calculus I derivative.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, in (c)  I have to compute $Df(0,0)r'(0)$. Would you be so kind to explain what this means/implies? (Should I take the derivative of the product, or individual derivatives? Won't it always result in zero since $f(0,0)$ is defined to be zero?)

Comment: It means take the derivative of $f$ and then evaluate it at $(0,0)$: $(Df)(0,0)$.  Also take the deriative of $r$ and then evaluate it at $0$: $r'(0)$.  Then multiply the two together.  No, $(Df)(0,0)$ need not be $0$ just because $f(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: I can't say I understand that question, though because $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.